# Spiral Matrix in c in 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, traversal, spiral

I am trying to write a  c program for sipral matrix in 2D array. which output should be as follows.I have done coding of matrix output but cannot do the output of Spiral Matrix. I can no find out the fault in my program. Please help

**Output**

The Given Matrix:

```
3 6 3 8
4 7 1 9
3 8 2 7
5 2 9 8
```

Output of Helically Traverse:

```
3 6 3 8 9 7 8 9 2 5 3 4 7 1 2 8
```

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int row = 0, //top most row
     b =row-1,  // bottom  row
     col= 0,    // left most column
     r = col-1, // right column
     size = 0,
     matrix[10][10],
     i;
    int dir;

printf("\n Size of Matrix: "); // enter the size of Matrix//
scanf("%d", &size); 

printf("\n  Enter Matrix Elements: \n");  // Enter Matrix Element//
for(row=0;row<size;row++)    // looping for enter row//
{
    for(col=0;col<size;col++)  // looping for enter column//
    {
        printf("    Element [%d][%d] :", row,col); // print output of element. say  Element[1][0]=  //
        scanf("%d" , &matrix[row][col]); // input matrix element //
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n the given Matrix is :\n"); // print output of given Matrix //

    for(row=0;row<size;row++) // looping for row//
    {
        for(col=0;col<size;col++) // looping for column//
        {
            printf("%4d",matrix[row][col]); //output of matrix//
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("output of helical traverse matrix is: \n");

    while(col<=r && row<=b) //condition exist if left column<= right column && Topmost row<= bottom row.I set four direction. dir =0 for left to right , dir=1 for top to bottom, dir 2 for right to left, dir 4 for bottom to top.//
    {
        if(dir==0){
            for(i=col;i<=r;i++){

                printf("%4d",matrix[row][i]); //print out 3 6 3 8//
            }
                row++;  //increase top row .so now 2 nd row become the top most row// 
            }

        else if(dir==1){
            for(i=row;i<=b;i++){      // looping for print output 9 7 8

                printf("%4d",matrix[i][col-1]); 
            }

                r--; //decrease left column. so now 2nd column from the right becomes the right most column//

        }
        else if(dir==2)
        {
            for(i=r;i>=col;i--){ //looping for print output of 9 2 5//

                printf("%4d",matrix[b][i]);
            }

                b--; //decerase bottom row. so now 2 nd row from bottom becomes the bottom row.//

        }
        else if(dir==3)
        {
            for(i=b;i>=row;i--){ //looping for print out 3 4//

                printf("%4d",matrix[i][col]);
            }
                col++; //icrease left column. so now 2nd column from left becomes left most column//

        }
        dir=(dir+1)%4;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Row and col are always equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-setting of the variable is necessary.,

```
r=b=size-1;
col=row=0;
dir=0;
while(col<=r && row<=b)
{
...
     printf("%4d",matrix[i][b]);//printf("%4d",matrix[i][col-1]);
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your code.

Comment: @JasonMc92 I have pointed out to be corrected in the code.

Comment: @JasonMc92  : I have added explanation

Comment: @Paul Roub : Please explain the resetting in details. I am trying but it is not showing any output of spiral order.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Please tell me where i have done wrong?

Comment: @user3193794 ; See by examining the value of each variable before entering the while-loop.